# server.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation error Angular Universal

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, firebase-hosting, angular-universal

I'm trying to integrate Angular Universal into my app, for SEO, following [this guide](https://codeible.com/view/videotutorial/XTwjaMmUAHuRPPCLUnbQ)

Run through it just fine until I got to the point where I'm supposed to use the new build command, `npm run build:ssr`. That's when I run into the error in the title

```
./server.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: recruit-kenya\server.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at recruit-kenya\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:64:26
```

I did some troubleshooting online, and the general fix for this type of error was to make sure it's declared in one of your .json files, usually pointing at tsconfig.app.json, specifically the `files` or `include` arrays, so I went ahead and did that. Still nothing. Saw some suggestions to restart, tried it and nothing as well, so I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

I will say, the only difference between my files and the ones in the tutorial are in the `server.ts` file, where I had to import environment myself. Mentioning it just in case I messed up somehow.
Code below

`tsconfig.app.json:`

```json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
        "types": []
    },
    "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts", "server.ts"],
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "server.ts"]
}
```

`angular.json:`

```json
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "recruit-kenya": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                },
                "@schematics/angular:application": {
                    "strict": true
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/functions/browser",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                        "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
                        "scripts": ["node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.js"]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                                    "maximumError": "4kb"
                                }
                            ],
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputHashing": "all"
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "buildOptimizer": false,
                            "optimization": false,
                            "vendorChunk": true,
                            "extractLicenses": false,
                            "sourceMap": true,
                            "namedChunks": true
                        }
                    },
                    "defaultConfiguration": "production"
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "recruit-kenya:build:production"
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "browserTarget": "recruit-kenya:build:development"
                        }
                    },
                    "defaultConfiguration": "development"
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "recruit-kenya:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                        "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
                        "scripts": ["node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.js"],
                        "preserveSymlinks": true
                    }
                },
                "deploy": {
                    "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
                    "options": {
                        "prerender": false,
                        "ssr": false,
                        "browserTarget": "recruit-kenya:build:production",
                        "firebaseProject": "recruit-kenya",
                        "firebaseHostingSite": "recruit-kenya"
                    }
                },
                "server": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/functions/browser",
                        "main": "server.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
                    }
                },
                "serve-ssr": {
                    "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "recruit-kenya:build",
                        "serverTarget": "recruit-kenya:server"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "recruit-kenya:build:production",
                            "serverTarget": "recruit-kenya:server:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "prerender": {
                    "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
                    "options": {
                        "routes": ["/"]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "recruit-kenya:build:production",
                            "serverTarget": "recruit-kenya:server:production"
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "browserTarget": "recruit-kenya:build:development",
                            "serverTarget": "recruit-kenya:server:development"
                        }
                    },
                    "defaultConfiguration": "production"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "recruit-kenya"
}
```

And here's the `server.ts` file just in case it's the culprit:

```ts
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
    const server = express();
    const websiteFileLocation = environment.production ? 'browser' : 'dist/functions/browser';
    const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), websiteFileLocation);
    const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html'))
        ? 'index.original.html'
        : 'index';

    // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
    server.engine(
        'html',
        ngExpressEngine({
            bootstrap: AppServerModule,
        })
    );

    server.set('view engine', 'html');
    server.set('views', distFolder);

    // Example Express Rest API endpoints
    // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
    // Serve static files from /browser
    server.get(
        '*.*',
        express.static(distFolder, {
            maxAge: '1y',
        })
    );

    // All regular routes use the Universal engine
    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
    });

    return server;
}

function run(): void {
    const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

    // Start up the Node server
    const server = app();
    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = (mainModule && mainModule.filename) || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
    run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

`main.server.ts:`

```ts
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
```